# Numpy: invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: arrays, numpy, type-conversion

How do I convert a Python array into a NumPy array, retaining the mixed datatypes, but replacing the tuples (parentheses) with square brackets instead?  You will notice that the first 3 columns start off as int, float, float and the last column is a string.  But in Block 3, all of them become strings!

Below is my output:

```
[(29606, 30.120779  , -97.309574  , 'DPCS')
 (29606, 30.2312951 , -97.6918021 , 'DPCS')
 (29606, 30.1682102 , -97.6160325 , 'DPCS')
 (40880, 40.56634232, -83.10456486, 'RN')
 (40880, 40.58765221, -83.14444627, 'RN')
 (40880, 40.58286847, -83.12839945, 'RN')]
Block 2
[[29606, 30.120779, -97.309574, 'DPCS'], [29606, 30.2312951, -97.6918021, 'DPCS'], [29606, 30.1682102, -97.6160325, 'DPCS'], [40880, 40.5663423172498, -83.1045648601189, 'RN'], [40880, 40.5876522144065, -83.1444462730164, 'RN'], [40880, 40.5828684683826, -83.1283994529175, 'RN']]
Block 3
[['29606' '30.120779' '-97.309574' 'DPCS']
 ['29606' '30.2312951' '-97.6918021' 'DPCS']
 ['29606' '30.1682102' '-97.6160325' 'DPCS']
 ['40880' '40.5663423172498' '-83.1045648601189' 'RN']
 ['40880' '40.5876522144065' '-83.1444462730164' 'RN']
 ['40880' '40.5828684683826' '-83.1283994529175' 'RN']]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The above comes from code:

```
import numpy
import pandas
from geopy.distance import great_circle
import utility_functions as uf
import timeit
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist, euclidean
import itertools
from itertools import groupby
import numpy_indexed as npi

# normalization thresholds
DISTANCE_LOWER_THRESH = 0
DISTANCE_UPPER_THRESH = 50


#class for scoring and updating the matrix of scores between workers (rows) and patients (columns).
class WorkerPatientScores:

    def __init__(self, dist_weight=1):

        self.a = []

        self.a = ([(29606, 30.120779, -97.309574, 'DPCS'),
                   (29606, 30.2312951, -97.6918021, 'DPCS'),
                   (29606, 30.1682102, -97.6160325, 'DPCS'),
                   (40880, 40.5663423172498, -83.1045648601189, 'RN'),
                   (40880, 40.5876522144065, -83.1444462730164, 'RN'),
                   (40880, 40.5828684683826, -83.1283994529175, 'RN')])

        dt = numpy.dtype('int, float, float, object')  # datatypes

        ndarray = numpy.array(self.a, dtype=dt)
        print(ndarray)

        ndarray2 = [[i[0], i[1], i[2], i[3]] for i in ndarray]
        print("Block 2")
        print(ndarray2)

        # Below removes previous datatypes
        ndarray3 = numpy.array(ndarray2)
        print("Block 3")
        print(ndarray3)
```

When I instead change the above LOC to:

> ndarray3 = numpy.array(ndarray2, dtype=dt)

I get the error:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'DPCS'

Answer (score 2):

`ndarray` is a valid structured array with 4 fields.

`ndarray2` (misnamed) is a list of lists.  You iterate on the elements (rows) of `ndarray`, and for each extract the field elements.

`ndarray3` uses the common format, the string.

Note that `self.a` is a list of tuples.  That's critical when creating a structured array.

```
alist = [(i[0], i[1], i[2], i[3]) for i in ndarray]
np.array(alist, dtype=dt)
```

should work.  `alist` is a list of tuples.

---

`ndarray.tolist()` also produces that list of tuples.

`np.array(..., object)` works with either a list of lists or list of tuples.

Object dtype arrays have their place, but aren't processed in the same way as structured arrays, nor in the same way as numeric arrays.  Each has their place.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I understand what you're saying, but I needed to keep it in the above format.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out!

> ndarray3 = numpy.array(ndarray2, dtype=object)

Comment: You could also use `np.array(self.a, object)` or `np.array(ndarray.tolist(), object)`.  You don't need the `ndarray2` intermediary.